# Is it possible to make django-rest-framework url patterns take params in non-specific order?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm looking in to adding a rest API to an IP management webapp I'm making.  I want the API to respond to multi-parameter queries with information about networks regardless of the order of the params.  I want:

```
ipmanager.com/api/customer_id/54331/network_category/iscsi
```

to return the same thing as:

```
ipmanager.com/api/network_category/iscsi/customer_id/54331
```

but I'm not having luck so far finding documentation on how to make the arguments to the api position agnostic.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're specifying the parameter in urls.py, it is not possible. But maybe you can try in a different way.

```
ipmanager.com/api/?network_category=iscsi&customer_id=54331
```

in your get_queryset method, try to get the parameter like this.

```
network_category = request.query_params.get('network_category', None)
customer_id = request.query_params.get('customer_id', None)
```

In your urls.py file, add this to your url patterns:

```
url(r'^api/get_customer', views.get_customer, name='get customer'),
```

The thing is, you don't have to specify anything in your urls.py. You can just give the parameter and extract it on your view.

I usually take one parameter, so I'm not sure it this would work but give it a try and let me know please.

Also, don't forget to change your url in urls.py. If you're not sure how to do it, I can help.

Comment: Sure, give me a hint on the url patterns update to accept arbitrary post data like this.  Thanks for the assist.

Comment: OK I've updated my answer. As I said, you don't have to specify anything for parameters in urls.py .

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. You'll need to define several urls to point on the same view.